# Wait statement not working in bash with nested scripts

Tags: bash, shell, wait

I have an issue with wait statement that is not working in bash.

I have a set of benchmarks in 100 folders. Each folder has the executable and a script file called *runBenchmark.sh* which launches each executable with a set of arguments like this

```
./benchmark_00 -v arg1 arg2 &
```

Now, I have a master script file *runSet.sh* which loops through all these folders and runs the individual *runBenchmark.sh* scripts. This works fine

Finally, I have a larger *main script* which at one point calls this *runSet.sh* in a loop which repeats 50 times. Inside the loop, I have

```
for ((i=0; i<50;i=i+1))
do
   runSet.sh
   wait
done
```

My expectation is to have the set run to completion in each loop, and that the next loop will not call any of the benchmarks until the current set has completed execution. However, what I am observing is that instead of launching the 100 benchmarks as a set in each loop, the wait statement is ignored and the loop just keeps launching the executables continuously.

If I write this inside the loop instead of runSet.sh, it works fine.

```
./benchmark_00 -v arg1 arg2 &
./benchmark_01 -v arg3 arg4 &
              .
              .
./benchmark_99 -v arg5 arg6 &
```

Any ideas of what is wrong when wait is used with calling scripts? Thanks

Comment: In your case `wait` waits for the runSet.sh process to finish, and this one finishes very quickly because it launches the benchmark in background (do not wait for it). So basically your main script waits almost nothing.

Comment: I realized that this is the case but I am looking for a fix

Answer (score 0):

Your `wait` should be part of `runSet.sh`. So remove `wait` from the `for loop` and add `wait` inside `runSet.sh` and check, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ((i=0; i<50;i=i+1))
do
   . runSet.sh
   wait
done
```

add a dot and space before calling runSet.sh. This will preventing spawning new shell thread and will be executed in-line.